# PHP AJAX - Pass a PHP value from one page to another using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to pass a php variable onto another php page (category-get-secondary.php) through Ajax. I have the following code:

```
function getSecondaryCat(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "category-get-secondary.php",
            data: 'primary_cat='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
            }
        });
    }
```

On `category-get-secondary.php` I want to get the value: -

```
$postPrimaryCat = $_POST['primary_cat'];
$categoryType = $_POST['category-select'];
```

$postPrimaryCat is transferred. Now I want to transfer the value for $categoryType.

I would like to pass the PHP variable 'category-select'. This is what I tried to transfer the value:

```
function getSecondaryCat(val,cat_val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "category-get-secondary.php",
            data:'primary_cat='+val+'&category-select='+cat_val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
            }
        });
    }
```

and to get the value I'm using

`$getCategorySet = $_POST['category-select'];`

but the value doesn't seem to be transfereed

**Updated with full code:**

main-page.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

</script>
<script>


function getSecondaryCat(val, catval) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "category-get-secondary.php",
            data:'primary_cat='+val+'&categoryselect='+catval,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
            }
        });
    }

    function selectCountry(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);
        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }
</script>

<?php

//Get category set from URL bar
$_POST['categoryselect'] = 'premium';
```

category-get-secondary.php

```
<?php
//Insert value to ajax
$postCatType = $_POST['categoryselect'];
```

Comment: Use this :  data:{primary_cat:val,category-select:cat_val}

Comment: The value 'category-select' still does not get outputted. To transfer it from the first page I am using `$_POST['category_select'] = 'private';`

Comment: @user6043723, Try to change your variable from `category-select` to `category_select`

Answer (score 1):

Valid Characters

**In general JavaScript, variable/function names can't contain** `-`. They can **only contain** `letters, $, and _ (Underscore)`

So... change data:`'primary_cat='+val+'&category-select='+cat_val, to this data:'primary_cat='+val+'&category_select='+cat_val,`

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Hi. I tried that method too... but it didn't work either

Comment: Change this $getCategorySet = $_POST['category-select']; to  $getCategorySet = $_POST['category_select'];

Comment: Hi, no it didn't unfortuantely

Comment: It is a bit confusing what you want to do but as per what i understand you want to pass "premium" as categoryselect to another page.

Use this: 
data:'primary_cat='+val+'&categoryselect=premium',

Comment: How can I pass the php string `premium` as a php string, as the value `premium' may change.

Comment: yeah than show me how you are calling the ajax function.

Comment: $_POST['categoryselect'] = 'private';

Comment: You will have to call ajax function on some event may be or let me know when you want to pass data to another page.

Comment: Its on a change event... its a auto populated drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSecondaryCat(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "category-get-secondary.php",
            data: {primary_cat:val},
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The value is not being output in the `category-get-secondary.php` To transfer it from the first page I am using $_POST['category_select'] = 'private';

Answer (score 0):

Change data and add below data line in your code.
**Ajax**

```
function getSecondaryCat(val,cat_val) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "category-get-secondary.php",
                data:{primary_cat:val,category_select:cat_val} ,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                    $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
                }
            });
        }
```

**PHP**

```
$postPrimaryCat = $_POST['primary_cat'];
$categoryType = $_POST['category-select'];
```

Comment: try to change "category-select" to "category_select". @user6043723

Comment: Hi. How do I initialise the primary value to send it through the AJAX. I tried  `$_POST['category-select'] = 'private';`